# Controlling dimension of html in Jquery .load("") function

Tags: jquery, html

I have one page in tab.

`id="plots-tabs-map"`

**JQuery Code:**

```
$('#plots-tabs-map').load("frontend/js/map.html")
```

How can I control its dimension as in my case it is going outside of the fixed dimension.

Comment: Is it `class="plots-tabs-map"` or is it `id="plots-tabs-map"`? We need more code to help you with your problem. What you provided doesn't explain much (at least not to me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that you can may first add width attribute to `id="plots-tabs-map"`
using jQuery

```
$('#plots-tabs-map').attr('style','width:200px');
```

Then you may find the id or classes of the content inside **frontend/js/map.html** and apply style to them.